# How to display the bootstrap modal adjacent to a particular div element or any other element.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

```
I have three or four div  or u l, l i /l i l i /l i /u l(u l=u+l and l i=l+i tags), If i mouse over on a particular div or u l or l i then it should display the modal(consist of edit and delete options) adjacent to that particular div u l or l i tags.
```

I tried the Showing a modal after mouse over but modal is appearing to the right top of the page.

//Code for the Model

```
<div class="modal fade col-sm-3" id="myModal" role="dialog" data-backdrop="">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                <a href="javascript:;" onclick="" title=""><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Remove</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" onclick="" title=""><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Change Permissions</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" onclick="" title=""><i class="fa fa-cog text-muted"></i> Settings</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

//JQuery Code

```
$("#pwidcontainer").on("mouseenter", "li", function () { //Main outer Container consist li element

            $('#myModal').modal('toggle');

            $(".div_pw").addClass("after_modal_appended"); // one of the li of that main container

            $(".modal-backdrop").appendTo(".div_pw");  //to append model adjucent to the li where we can make edit/delete         
        });
```

If i mouseover on any div_pw it should display the model(small that one i have created) adjacent to that particular div only.

Comment: did you try to use bootstrap tooltips? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/ . Either popovers?

Answer (score 0):

> We have the following HTML Structure
>
> ```
> <div>
>   <button id="btn">Open Modal</button>
>   <div class="red block">
>   </div>
>   <div class="blue block">     
>   </div>  
> </div>
> ```
>
> Now what we need to do is to open a bootstrap modal inside the blue
>   div on the click of a button.
>
> So to do so follow the steps given below :-
>
> 1. Write the HTML code for the bootstrap modal inside the blue div .
>
>    Open Modal
>
>    ```
>        <!-- Modal content-->
>        <div class="modal-content">
>          <div class="modal-header">
>            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
>            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
>          </div>
>          <div class="modal-body">
>            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
>          </div>
>          <div class="modal-footer">
>            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
>          </div>
>        </div>
>
>      </div>
>    </div>
>    ```
> 2. Write the following Javascript Code
>
>    $(document).ready(function(){
>
>    ```
>     $("body").on("click","#btn",function(){
>
>          $("#myModal").modal("show");
>
>          //appending modal background inside the blue div
>          $('.modal-backdrop').appendTo('.blue');   
>
>          //remove the padding right and modal-open class from the body tag which bootstrap adds when a modal is shown
>          $('body').removeClass("modal-open")
>          $('body').css("padding-right","");     
>      });
>    ```
>
>    });
> 3. Write the following CSS for it
>
>    .red
>      {
>        background-color:red;
>      }
>
>    .blue
>      {
>        background-color:blue;
>        position:relative;// so that .modal & .modal-backdrop gets positioned relative to it
>      }
>
>    .block
>      {
>        width:100%;
>        height:200px;
>      }
>
>    .modal, .modal-backdrop {
>          position: absolute !important;
>      }
> 4. That’s It

https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-display-a-bootstrap-modal-inside-a-div/